# WP_Query articles order by offset in collumns

Tags: posts, query-posts, pre-get-posts

The code below wants to show a list of articles in two collumns.

```
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=35&offset=0' );
    while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();
    $i++;
    ?>

    <?php if ($i == "1") { ?>
    <div style="padding-top: 10px; float: left; width: 50%;">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php } ?>


    <?php if (in_array($i, array(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))) { ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php } ?>

   <?php if ($i == 10) { ?>
            </div>
   <?php } ?>

    <?php if ($i == "2") { ?>
        <div style="padding-top: 10px; float: right; width: 50%;">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>          
    <?php } ?>

    <?php endwhile;?>
```

The problem is: the article with $i = 2 appears below article with $i = 1. It is not the order that I used in code above.

How can I arrange articles in this order?

PS: my articles with $i=2 appears in first collumn (aligned left) too, because of `</div>` after article with $i=10.

If you have some questions, or if you don't understand, I'm here.

EDIT:

My code:

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=35&offset=0' );
while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();
$titles[] = get_the_title();               
$excerpts[] = get_the_excerpt(); 
endwhile;
?>
```

To display first article:

```
<?php
echo $titles[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo $excerpts[0];
?>
```

Is code above ok for server speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the posts in two different arrays, then loop over both separately:

```
$columns      = array ( 'first' => array (), 'second' => array () );
$first_column = array( 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 );

// separation
foreach ( $the_query->posts as $index => $post )
{
    if ( in_array( $index + 1, $first_column ) )
        $columns[ 'first' ][] = $post;
    else
        $columns[ 'second' ][] = $post;
}

unset ( $post );

// render one column
echo 'First column<br>';
foreach ( $columns[ 'first' ] as $p )
{
    print $p->ID
        . get_the_title( $p ) . '<br>'
        . get_the_post_thumbnail( $p->ID ) . '<br>';
}

// render the next column
echo 'Second column<br>';
foreach ( $columns[ 'second' ] as $p )
{
    print $p->ID
        . get_the_title( $p ) . '<br>'
        . get_the_post_thumbnail( $p->ID ) . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: can you help me please? I'm trying to shot post id, featured image etc, but it doesn;t show anything

Comment: @ITChristian I made an update to my answer to show how to get the thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks @toscho ! I will publish my own code, to tell me if is ok if i will use it

Comment: I've edited my question @toscho

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a much simpler way [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-show-front-pagelatest-posts-in-two-columns#post-4500258):

```
@media screen and (min-width : 640px){

.home ul.index > li{

    display:inline-block;
    clear:none;
}

.home .index > li:nth-child(odd){

    width:50%;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    clear:both;
}
.home .index > li:nth-child(even){

    width:46%;
    float:right;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}}
```

Comment: Don't just dump code and links as answers, please give a small explanation to why this code will work